# Bootstrap 3 - grid system and thumbnail

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My grid system is like that:

[image]

I want to put it side by side. I'm trying to do that:

[image]

My code actually is:

```
 <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-4'>...</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
 </div>
```

How can I do that? I'm looking in the internet (google, forum, ...), but it's hard to find. I'm trying to use only bootstrap. I don't want plugins or something like that.

Comment: What doesn't work? Those pictures look the same to me.

Comment: You know what columns are right? You probably want your 4th element inside the first column then. And read about the bootstrap naming scheme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario you should keep only 3 columns for grid and move 4th column content to first column.

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">... [add 4th column content here]</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">...</div>
</div>
```

But it also depends what you want to have on smaller resolutions.

Comment: I put them align vertically with 3 columns and the contents inside them. #Myenglishisbad :) Now works